# Weird mouse problem Linux Mint

Tags: mouse, cinnamon, lxde, lightdm, cursor

I have linux mint 17.1 cinnamon 32bit. I installed these packages:

```
lxde lubuntu-core lubuntu-icon-theme lubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I selected `lightdm` as defaut. After that I log off and log in on lubuntu desktop enviroment. Everything was fine till restart. After restart my mouse looks like this (cursor doesn't show up in screenshot):

[image: test]

I tried first to remove `lightdm` and reverting back to `mdm`. Then i unistalled all packages that i have installed before. But no success. I think it has something to do with x server but i cant figure out what is it exactly. Note: If i try to change cursor style the shape remain the same, only color will change.

Comment: That's usually a video driver bug. And often the only thing you can do is to upgrade or downgrade the driver.

Comment: Were any mdm dependencies removed? Did you run  sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm?

Comment: I tried to remove dependencies too but no result. I reinstalled and I will never install any other desktop enviroment alongside Cinnamon.